# can Polymer be used with an embedded web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer, material-design

I want to make an embedded ruby on rails web app (used only over a closed LAN) which will be based on Material Design using Polymer for web components. Is that possible? It would mean that all of the Polymer components would have to be bundled into the app and not imported over the web.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just add all of the polymer code/assets that you want to include to your app, either by using the asset pipeline or dump them into the public directory.